# VBA get text from HTML webpage when multiple class

Tags: html, vba

I'm using VBA to get values from a webpage. among other element, the HTML contains the following data.

```
 <div class="column03"  >
 <!-- IE11 remediation changes -->
    <span class="outputLabel" id="sessionHeaderProgressBarColumn03"  >Alt ID:</span><span class="outputText">925216444</span>
</div>
```

based on the above HTML code the ID return 925216444, however my VBA code either returns the value of Alt ID:, or [Object]

code:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("sessionHeaderProgressBarColumn03")
```

another

```
IE.Document.getElementById("sessionHeaderProgressBarColumn03").inntertext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim e

Set e = IE.Document.getElementById("sessionHeaderProgressBarColumn03")    

Debug.Print e.nextSibling.innerText
'or
Debug.Print e.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
```